# Azure service bus | Re process dead letter messages back to queue | How to receive all messages from dead letter queue?

Tags: c#, azure, servicebus

I want to integrate the processing of messages back to Queue using a Unique Identifier as user inputs. How to fetch all the messages from the dead letter in a single call instead of looping it multiple times?

```
        var msRequestIdArg = MsRequestIds.Split('\n').Select(e => e.Trim()).ToList();
        var msRootRequestArg = MsRootRequestIds.Split('\n').Select(e => e.Trim()).ToList();
        var queueClient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ServiceBusConnectionString, QueueName);
        var factory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(ServiceBusConnectionString);
        var deadLetterPath = QueueClient.FormatDeadLetterPath(QueueName);
        var deadLetterQueueReceiver = factory.CreateMessageReceiver(deadLetterPath, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
        deadLetterQueueReceiver.PrefetchCount = 10;
        var messageResponse = new List<Tuple<string, bool, string>>();
        var counter = msRequestIdArg.Count + msRootRequestArg.Count;

        while (counter > 0)
        {
            var brokeredMessage = await deadLetterQueueReceiver.ReceiveAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't and should not.

Imagine you'd have hundreds of thousands, if not millions, of messages that need to be returned. Can you imagine the constraints on both the broker and the clients with this amount of messages that need to be transferred? Failures are expected to happen, and with a very large number of messages, you'd be quickly finding yourself in a situation when a call such as this one would consistently fail, rendering your system helpless.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I understand that we should create a listener to track any upcoming message. However, in my case, I need a better way to receive messages  from queue. As `Receivce()` loops and fetch a single messge each time. I am not expecting huge number of data.

Comment: Define "something better", assuming there are scenario I was referring to. Also, `ReceiveAsync()` can receive multiple messages, just not all of them.